# Laravel and Pusher. Error connecting. Issue with App key

Tags: events, laravel-5, websocket, pusher, real-time-updates

Just started to use `Pusher` for my `Laravel` application. I am using Laravel's `Event Broadcasting`.

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
var pusher = new Pusher("{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}");
//console.log(pusher);
var channel = pusher.subscribe('superadmin');

    channel.bind('NewUser', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
});
```

**ISSUE**

> Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4001,"message":"Could not find app by key MY_PUSHER_APP_KEY. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong cluster."}}}

**ALREADY VERIFIED**

1. Pusher App Credentials.
2. Cluster mentioned in `config/broadcasting.php` is the same provided by `Pusher`
3. Restarted apache just to be sure.

Share your experiences with this issue.

Answer (score 10):

You must specify the cluster when you initialize Pusher if you're not using the default region. For instance:

```
const socket = new Pusher(APP_KEY, { cluster: 'eu' });
```

Does this solve your problem? See [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#cluster-string) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `{{ cluster: 'eu' }}` after your APP_KEY. It will work

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I was using PUSHER_APP_ID instead of PUSHER_APP_KEY